# How to change the transparency of the breakpoint line background in NetBeans?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

The background of lines which have a line breakpoint in NetBeans 8.2 is so dark and opaque that one can hardly read the code (at least not words in black which make up most of the code):

[image]

This was much better in 8.1. How to change/restore this setting (I don't care about the specified color and transparency, it should be something that allows to read `System.` and `println` without approaching the screen)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Tools > Options > Font And colors > Tab "Annotations" and change the back ground color of Breakpoint.

[image]

Comment: Thank for your answer. I seem to suffer from a bug (https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=270700) which display multiple "Breakpoint" entries and changes to the background don't have any effect. The development snapshot 201705210001 doesn't have the "Fonts & Colors" section in options. I'll give feedback as soon as I make progress with trying it out (marking an answer correct which I didn't try doesn't seem wise).

Comment: Thank you for up voting.You can check each break point entries and if background colour matches with the colour you shared in your question then changing it will affect the bg colour. If this solves your problem you can mark it as accepted answer.